# How to mock module const map?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

While writing tests, assuming mocking module level map is required. How can I mock not exported `cacheMap` using jest for tests?

```
const cacheMap = new Map<string, string>();
export function add(key: string, value: string) {
  cacheMap.set(key, value);
}
export function remove(key: string) {
  cacheMap.delete(key);
}
```

Comment: Mock it to use it how? You can just do `mockMap = { get() { return "my value"'; } }` and that might be enough.

Comment: I need to test module's add/remove methods

Comment: Then it seems you want a spy, not a mock.

Comment: notice cacheMap is unexported, would spy work?

Comment: I thought spy is for tracking if request reached for var, but I thought mock suits for stubbing or replacing var value?

Comment: Well, no. But neither would a mock. You need to restructure your code either way if you want to intercept `cacheMap`. That is *if* you really want to. I wouldn't unit test such trivial of a module code there is some sort of requirement for 100% test coverage.

Comment: A mock is a fake implementation that does nothing. Or just does one thing but basically has no logic in it. It's just there so it can be used by other code without that code throwing an error. A spy is something you can interrogate later to see if it's used. If you want to test this module you need to make sure that `add` calls `set` with the correct parameters. You can do that with a spy. If you just mock `cacheMap` then your test can only be "if I call `add` does it throw an error" and since *you* control the mock, your test becomes "if I make the mock throw an error, does it throw an error"

Answer (score 0):

You add an optional parameter with a default value like this. And while you're testing you inject the Map you want, overriding the global one.

```js
const cacheMap = new Map<string, string>();
export function add(key: string, value: string, map: Map = cacheMap) {
  cacheMap.set(key, value);
}
export function remove(key: string, map: Map = cacheMap) {
  cacheMap.delete(key);
}

test('add', () => {
  const map = new Map<string, string>()
  add('a', 'b', map);
  expect(map.get('a')).toBe('b')
})
```

Comment: I don't want to pass map. I want to mock module map with mocked one.

Comment: you want to mock the native `Map` ?

Comment: The const `cacheMap` is just an instance of Map. If you're using the native map then do as I said, because we don't go around testing native modules. What you want to test is the code YOU wrote.